# Django ORM binary exact

Tags: sql, django, django-orm

I am aware of the collation case sensitivy that is not Django dependent but rather database dependent as stated [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/databases/#mysql-collation).

Suppose I have a MySQL database with a _ci (case insensitive) collation with a table like this:

```
|ID  | name  |
--------------
|0   | John  |
```

Being case insensitive, if I query either way:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE name = "john"
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE name = "John"
```

Would return the element.

Django obviously acts the same way:

```
MyObject.objects.get(name="john")
```

Would return the instance.

In MySQL I can query like this to force case sensitivity:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE BINARY name = "john"
```

That would return me nothing

My question is: **How to replicate the Binary query operator using the Django ORM?**

Comment: You can use the `exact` lookup as ***`MyObject.objects.get(name__exact="john")`***. BTW, this is not the *binary lookup*, but will result the same result.

Comment: Unfortunately, it won't work, as stated by the docs here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/
 Entry.objects.get(headline__exact="Cat bites dog") Would generate SQL along these lines: 
SELECT ... WHERE headline = 'Cat bites dog';

Comment: More explicitly said here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#exact

Comment: That's what I already mentioned, this will return the same result, ie, ***database will return the exact matched items***. Also, I am aware that this is not making a SQL BINARY query